# Saving output of a batch file on network location

Tags: batch-file, windows-networking

I have lifted bits and pieces of the code from multiple places and have made the below code.

The functionality of this code is basically to read all softwares and save it in a csv format so I can use it further. I want the code to save output on a folder which is on another computer which is shared on the domain. Below is the code:

```
@ECHO OFF 
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set OutputFile=C:\Domo\%computername%.csv
echo "Computer","Key","Version","Name","Publisher">"%OutputFile%"

call :getsw "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
call :getsw "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
call :getsw "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

ENDLOCAL
exit /b

:getsw
    for /F "delims=" %%g in ('reg query "%~1" 2^>NUL') do (
        set "_swRegKey=%%~g"
        set "_swName="
        set "_swVers="
        set "_swPub="

        for /F "tokens=1,2,*" %%G in ('
          reg query "%%~g" /V DisplayName 2^>NUL ^| findstr /I "DisplayName"
                                      ') do set "_swName=%%~I" 
        for /F "tokens=1,2,*" %%G in ('
          reg query "%%~g" /V DisplayVersion 2^>NUL ^| findstr /I "DisplayVersion"
                                      ') do set "_swVers=%%~I"
        for /F "tokens=1,2,*" %%G in ('
          reg query "%%~g" /V Publisher 2^>NUL ^| findstr /I "Publisher"
                                      ') do set "_swPub=%%~I"

        call :echosw 
        ) 
    exit /b

:echosw
    if "!_swName!!_swVers!"=="" (
        echo "%COMPUTERNAME%","unknown","!_swRegKey!","","">>"%OutputFile%"
    ) else (
        echo "%COMPUTERNAME%","!_swRegKey!","!_swVers!","!_swName!","!

_swPub!">>"%OutputFile%"
    )
    exit /b
```

The problem is when I change the location of outputfile (Line 3) from C:\Domo\%computername%.csv to a network location like \Win-p0sck5u2hqd\csv\%computername%.csv

This gives an error saying **access is denied** while executing the batch file. Is there anything I am missing. please help me understand why it is not working and is there any solution.

This location \Win-p0sck5u2hqd\ is accessible from my run command.

Comment: Have you tried putting it out on your second drive?

You could as well try to start the file as Administrator (right-click on it-> Run as Administrator) if you generally have to have certain permissions to access the network location.

Further... Don't you have two `\` at the start of a network location?

Last thing: Have you tried to output the value of `%OutputFile%` right before you try to place the file there? Maybe something went wrong somewhere...

Maybe anything helped there...

Comment: You should try to mount the remote directory using `NET USE X: \Win-p0sck5u2hqd\TargetDir`. Try to save it to the mounted drive and unmount it afterwards with `NET USE X: /delete /yes`

Comment: By the way, shouldn't it be `\\Win-p0sck5u2hqd\csv\%computername%.csv` rather than `\Win-p0sck5u2hqd\csv\%computername%.csv` (one \ missing at the beginning)?

Comment: Oops... I wanted to write the double-backslash-thing as well, but obviously I messed up the formatting...

Comment: Thanks Michael, adding net use Z: \\192.168.3.75\csv /User:xxx\xxx {Password} fixed it for me. 

Yes it is a double backslash. It was my typo. :)